# Empirical bayes approach to hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, poisson-distribution, empirical-bayes

Empirical Bayes seems to be quite successful in point estimation. A classical [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_Bayes_method) would be the Robbins' formula to estimate the Poisson rate. Robbins also published a [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1401373?seq=1) about the application of empirical Bayes to hypothesis testing in 1963. An example for testing Poisson rate was given in the section 4 based on the Robbins' formula. It seems that the approach proposed in this paper is not widely used. My question is whether this approach of directly applying empirical Bayes for testing hypotheses, would be recommended from today's point of view.